# Can an Immigrant freelance Web Developer survive in California, USA?

Tags: immigration, freelance, cost-of-living, california

I am a (28 y/o) freelance web developer from india. I m planning to move California on a random certificate course of 1 year from a community college to work as a freelance web developer. My main motive is to earn some bug buck in 2 years and come back.

I would like to know whether would i be able to survive with the set is skills i'm to offer there. If not, can you suggest me any state or city where freelancing web or app development is much valued.

Any answer is appreciated.

Comment: Your most important task would be to obtain a US visa that allows you to work. Without that, you cannot work in the US.

Comment: @GregHewgill Understood. How do I get one. I mean, i know if a company hires you they might help you obtaining one. But my question would be presuming i might be able to crack the interview in a generic tech job would it be possible for the said company to provide me the visa..?

Comment: @Ronak Have you done any research on obraining a US work visa? https://www.uscis.gov/working-in-the-united-states This site is not suited to ‘want a debate’ type questions.

Comment: Some student visas allow work, but I believe only part time because you're supposed to be studying with the rest of your time.

Comment: To add to @phoog's comment: part-time work for student visa-holders must be on-campus. I don't know if sitting in the campus library and working for a remote employer would qualify.

Comment: @phoog student visas allow part time working **on campus**, i.e.: for the college (as a teaching assistant, support stuff, etc).

Comment: @ronak how is a random certificate course from a community college related to working as a freelance web developer? Are you planning to commit visa fraud and lie to the USCIS and CBP about why you're coming to the US? That may backfire spectacularly, as any illegal scheme.

Comment: @littleadv during the second year, off-campus employment is permitted in at least some cases, but it must be related to the course of study, which it presumably would be in this case.

Comment: @phoog what second year? The OP mentioned "1 year random certificate course". Regardless, you're talking about CPT, which is different.

Comment: @littleadv I overlooked "1 year," but I was talking about OPT as well as CPT.  CPT is different from what exactly?  Suppose OP were in a 2- or 4-year program.  Would it not be possible to work 20 hours a week for 1 or 3 years?

Comment: @phoog OPT and CPT are essentially the same thing and are counted together. CPT is during the course of studies and OPT is after the completion. CPT is usually used for internships and OPT for full time past graduation while H1b is being processed. Neither is for self-employment.